# Can I write to a text file from a button in xPages?

Tags: xpages

I have an xPages application that needs to write a text file to a folder on my network.  I'm not sure if it's even possible from an xPages application?

If it is, can someone give me an idea how to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

POI4XPages can write views etc to CSV files https://poi4xpages.openntf.org/. I've previously used [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/), and Apache-licensed Java library to import from a CSV file, but it also allows exporting. I use it regularly to preload data for session databases like for my session at [Connect 2016](http://www.intec.co.uk/my-session-at-ibm-connect/). [CommonsCSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) has subsequently been released, which would replace OpenCSV.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I will check them out.  I need to write a custom text file with specific formats.  Would CommonCSV be more appropriate for that vs. POI4XPages?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. The easiest way is to create a Java class that does what you need (and test it from the command line). In a button, which is server side JavaScript, you can instantiate that class and write out.
You might need to handle security setting (e.g. deploying your class in a jar file into `[DominoAppDir]/jvm/lib/ext`) to be allowed to have network access. If you rather keep the class in the nsf, you might need [harder measures](https://wissel.net/blog/2013/05/dont-try-this-at-home.html).

Let us know how it goes

Comment: Thanks Stephan.  That sounds easy enough.  Have you had good success by deploying the .jar file to /ext ?

Comment: I write this stuff, like the POI4Xpages, as Domino OSGi plugin (mostly in an updatesite.nsf) so it doesn't get lost in reinstalls. Works around the access rights too. If POI does the trick - use that.

Comment: I'm afraid OSGI plug-ins are above my pay grade!

Answer (score 0):

I just created a simple class that created the file and wrote to it.  Worked like a champ

Thanks all!